# Structure theorem for locally bounded variation functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, geometric-measure-theory

I have some doubts reading *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy. In particular, they define the space of locally bounded variation functions $BV_{loc}(U)$ in $U\subset \mathbb R^n$, $U$ open, as the space of functions such that:

1. $f\in L^1_{loc}(U)$;
2. for all open $V\subset \subset U$ we have $\sup\{\int_V f\text{div}
           \phi dx:\phi\in C^1_c(V,\mathbb R^m),|\phi|\leq 1\}=C(V)<+\infty.$

**Notation**: $V\subset\subset U$ means: $\overline V$ is compact and $\overline{V}\subset U.$

Now, a structure theorem for functions of locally bounded variation holds (Theorem 1 pag. 167). Indeed, if $f\in BV_{loc}(U)$, the linear functional $L\colon\phi\mapsto \int_U f\text{div}\phi dx$ is "bounded" in the sense 2. above, so, by Riesz's representation theorem, one gets the existence of a Radon measure $\mu$ on $U$ and a $\mu$-measurable function $\sigma\colon U\to \mathbb R^m$ such that $|\sigma|=1, \mu$-a.e. and $$\int_U f \text{div}\phi dx=-\int_U\phi\cdot \sigma d\mu$$ for all $\phi\in C^1_c(U,\mathbb R^m).$

Now, I know that the measure $\mu$ is given by Riesz's representation theorem itself in the following way: at first, $\mu$ is defined on the open sets $O\subset U$ like this: $$\mu(O)=\sup\{\int_O f\text{div}
        \phi dx:\phi\in C^1_c(O,\mathbb R^m),|\phi|\leq 1\}.$$
Then, on all other subsets $B\subset U$, we put $$\mu(B)=\inf\{\mu(O):B\subset O, \,O \text{ open}\}.$$

What I don't understand is why, at page 170 of the book, there's written that $$\mu(V)=\sup\{\int_V f\text{div} \phi dx:\phi\in C^1_c(V,\mathbb R^m),|\phi|\leq 1\}$$ *for all $V\subset \subset U$*, without worrying that $V$ is open or not, but concerning only on the boundedness of $V$.

Can anyone help me figuring out this?

Comment: On page 261 you will find a note about the convention used throughout the book that $U, V, W$ denote open sets of Euclidean space. (And the statement is not correct for suitably chosen closed sets, e.g. an $n-1$ dimensional closed hypersurface).

Comment: Could you explain your last statement? By the way, even if they mean $V$ open, I'm not convinced, in the sense that I think $\mu(V)=\sup\{\dots\}$ for each *open* $V$ in $U$, not only for bounded open $V$.

Comment: If $f$ is the characteristic function of a set $E$ with bounded perimeter then the measure $||Df||$ associated with $f$ is concentrated on the reduced boundary of $E$. If $E $ is, say, the unit ball, then this is just an $n-1$ dimensional unit sphere. This is a set the interior of which is empty (so you won't find any nonzero differentiable $\phi$ with compact support in that set), but $||Df||(\partial E) >0$. I don't understand your other remark about unbounded sets. If they say it's true for each bounded open set they do not say it fails for unbounded open sets.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You're right, they don't say that it is true only when $V$ is bounded. But it seems that they are quite careful in seeing if $V$ is bounded or not in other parts of the chapter, but maybe for other purposes. I'm going to read it again, maybe I'm just missing something.